# Avoid dll pre-loading vulnerability by reloading dll, any better way?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

To avoid dll pre-loading I tried to use `SetDllDirectory("")` as it is mentioned in MSDN to remove current directory from search path.

> The directory to be added to the search path. If this parameter is an
>   empty string (""), the call removes the current directory from the
>   default DLL search order. If this parameter is NULL, the function
>   restores the default search order.

Surprisingly it didn't work. I can see dlls are still getting loaded from current directory if dll present there. I also tired to set dll directory path as system 32 path, but still it picks dll from current directory. Lastly I decide to get all the modules loaded in my application and reloading them again. My code looks like this,

```
if(wcsstr(szModName,L"TestLibrary.dll"))
{
   FreeLibrary(hMods[i]);
   LoadLibrary("SomeRelavantPath\TestLibrary.dll");
}
```

Do you see any problem with my code?

@Edit:
My Complete POC code,

```
int main( void )
{
    SetDllDirectory(L"");
    LPWSTR s = new WCHAR[100];
    GetDllDirectory(100,s);
    HINSTANCE myDLL = LoadLibrary(L"TestLibrary.dll");
    //myDLL returns non-null, there is file in current dir and not at any other location, it should have return null.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to `GetDllDirectory` immediately after you `SetDllDirectory("")`, and immediately before you `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @iehrlich Didn't work. Is there any reason calling `GetDllDirectory ` should work?

Comment: @PranitKothari, I suspect that what @iehrlich means is to use `GetDllDirectory` to make sure that the search path has indeed been changed to what you wanted. Did it change?

Comment: @PranitKothari, BTW, do you use `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL for the first time as well?

Comment: @yzt No it's added at runtime by some 3rd party library.

Comment: @iehrlich @yzt Got your point, `GetDllDirectory` does return empty string, but do same thing as earlier.

Comment: Two few info, but you should make sure that your 3rdparty does not call `SetDllDirectory` itself :)

Comment: Are you linking with a .lib file that causes TestLibrary.dll to be explicitly imported?

Comment: @iehrlich that could be a case. But I create sample project to write POC. Bare Win32 application, behavior is same.

Comment: @Anders No. Directly using LoadLibrary to link with dll. No .lib explicitly linked.

Comment: Is the working directory in your PATH variable somehow? If you look closely in the manual, PATH is searched as well - this means that even if you remove the directory from the first position in the search sequence, it'll still be traversed eventually if it's present in the PATH.

Comment: @iehrlich No it's not there in PATH.

Comment: Also, at this point, I hope you made sure that the DLL loaded is actually *your* DLL, right?

Comment: @iehrlich Didn't understand your point. I am giving explicit path.

Comment: Wait wait wait. Like, "C:\Work\MyApp\MyDll.dll" explicit?

Comment: @iehrlich Yes. That way.

Comment: These SetDll* functions only protects you from relative paths! There is no reason why a full path would load the wrong thing though.

Comment: Downvoting without mentioning any reason?

Comment: How is this even a problem? If malicious code has write access to your EXE's folder you've already lost the war.

Comment: @ChrisBecke Yes, my mistake. Wrong approach.

Comment: Also, the phrase "current directiory" is not synonymous with "application directory". Typically these are the same when launched from a debugger or explorer, but shortcuts, batch files - anything that calls CreateProcess can make them different. The directory that contains the EXE is always searched, independently of the current directory.

Comment: As an example see [Prevent DLL Hijacking Burn with Clean Room](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/)

Comment: As documented, `SetDllDirectory` alters the **search** path. When passing a fully qualified path name to `LoadLibrary`, no search is performed. Nothing of that is clear from your question. That is a good reason to cast a down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Unloading and loading again with a new path is pointless from a security perspective, it is already too late because a evil .dll could execute code in its DllMain!

The [best solution](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/) is to directly link to as few DLLs as possible and call [`SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310515(v=vs.85).aspx) before anything else in your WinMain function.

Comment: @Andres Thanks for quick response. I tried using `SetDefaultDllDirectories` as well. Encounter same problem. Also, I want to support Windows 7. It's min requirement is Win 8.

Comment: It is available on Vista and 7 if they have Windows Update turned on some time after 2011. Just GetProcAddress for it and if it is not there you just have to manually load things with a full path.

Comment: @Andres I tired `SetDefaultDllDirectories` and `LoadLibraryEx` combination on Wndows 10. API works there, problem remains the same.

Comment: Why are you using LoadLibraryEx? Any special flags? And I know SetDefaultDllDirectories works so you must be doing something strange.

Comment: If it works for you then it worth putting some time again. Between I am using  Visual Studio 2008, do you see any problem here?

Comment: It helps to protect you when you load something with a **relative path** but since you have not posted a usable example there is not much we can do.

Comment: @IInspectable I said it's POC.

Comment: @PranitKothari: And it isn't. It doesn't prove your observations, since no-one was informed, that your POC uses **fully qualified path names**.

Comment: @IInspectable where is fully qualified path?

Comment: @PranitKotharI: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320438/avoid-dll-pre-loading-vulnerability-by-reloading-dll-any-better-way/44320585?noredirect=1#comment75646512_44320438), but not in your [problem statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44320438/1889329). As such, it's useless. You have shown code to repro something that your code cannot repro. I'm stopping it here, though. You don't seem to be following simple concepts.

Answer (score 0):

> If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that path for the module.
>
> If the string specifies a relative path or a module name without a path, the function uses a standard search strategy to find the module; for more information, see the Remarks.

From [LoadLibrary function @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx).

Calls to `SetDllDirectory` will do nothing against full paths.

Comment: OK, so for my POC code I just used `LoadLibrary("TestLibrary.dll");`, and it loads dll from current dir. Now not sure if it is relative path?

Comment: Please post your full POC code in the question as an update.

Comment: Updated my question.